# What is Herbrand Model? And a proof of construction.

Tags: logic

I was reading "[A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-1221-3)," and encounter this interesting problem,

> Let $\mathcal{L}$ be $=$-free, $\mathcal{T}_0 \not = \emptyset$ the set of its ground terms, and $U \subseteq \mathcal{L}$ a consistent set of $\forall$-sentences. Construct a model $\mathcal{I} \models U$ on the domain $\mathcal{T}_0$ by setting $c^{\mathcal{I}} = c, f^{\mathcal{I}} \vec{t} :=f \vec{t}$ (hence $t^{\mathcal{I}} = t$ for all $t \in \mathcal{T}_0,$ shown by induction on $t$), and $r^{\mathcal{I}} \vec{t}: \iff X \vdash r\vec{t}$ ( $\vec{t} \in \mathcal{T}_0^n; X \supseteq U$ maximally consisten, so that $X \vdash \lnot \alpha \iff X \not \vdash \alpha$ for all $a \in \mathcal{L},$ cf. e.g. Lemma $1.4.4$). $\mathcal{I}$ is called a Herbrand model; see also $\textbf{4.1}.$

My question will be what is Herbrand model? Another question is how to construct it?

My effort for now:

We need to do rule induction on all the terms.

Lemma $1.$ $t^{\mathcal{I}} = t$ for all $t \in \mathcal{T}_0.$

Case $1.$ we know $\mathcal{T}_0$ has all the ground terms, meaning there is no free variables, so it will be either constants or terms without free variables. If it is the case for the constants, we immediately know that $c^{\mathcal{I}} = c.$ And we are done.

Case $2.$ we consider $f^{\mathcal{I}}\vec{t} = f\vec{t},$ where $\vec{t}$ has all the ground terms. By induction hypothesis, we know that $t^{\mathcal{I}} = t$ for any subterms of $\vec{t}$. So we can say that $\vec{t}^\mathcal{I}= \vec{t}.$ And using the fact that we have $f^{\mathcal{I}}$ and $f$ on the both sides, we will see that the conclusion holds naturally.

Lemma $2.$ we have a model.

Proof is a little bit involved. But I can show it to you if you find it helpful.

We assume there is an maximal consistent extension $X.$

$$\mathcal{I} \models r \vec{t} \iff X \vdash r \vec{t}.$$

$$\mathcal{I} \models \alpha \land \beta \iff \mathcal{I} \models \alpha , \beta \iff X \vdash \alpha, X \vdash \beta \iff X \vdash \alpha \land \beta.$$

By maximal consistency, we will have $\mathcal{I}  \models \lnot \alpha \iff X \vdash \lnot \alpha.$

We do not need to take care of $\mathcal{I} \models \forall x \alpha $ because it will force $\alpha$ has free variables. However, we assume $T_0$ to be ground variables.

So my proof is complete but is there any fault?